# Compact set of measure zero.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Is there $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, such that $A$ is compact, contains the origin and has measure zero?
I know that the finite set A, of the form $A=\{ x_{1},...,x_{n} \}$, is a set of measure zero, but I don't know about its compactness nor if one can include the element zero amoung its elements.

Comment: Why would 0, specifically, be any issue?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo, that is important because I'm looking for a closed set $A$, of measure zero so that $\mathbb{R}^n\A$ is connected. In my case, the set $\mathbb{R}^n\A$ can not contain the null element.

Comment: Whether 0 is in the set or not might end up being an issue for the task you are after, which involves connectedness and other assumptions you have not listed. It is irrelevant for the question you posted, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-trivial one would be the standard Cantor set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. It's closed, bounded (contained in the unit rectangle $[0,1]^n$, thus compact. It also contains the origin and is of measure zero.

Comment: first of all, thank you. In your answer, we have $A=[0,1]^n$, that's very nice and solved the question. Could we say that $\mathbb{R}^n$ \ $[0,1]^n$ is connected? It seems to me that the answer to this new question is NOT.

Comment: No, you misunderstand. We don't take $A = [0,1]^n$. That's a positive measure set. We take the standard $n$ dimensional Cantor Set, which is contained in $[0,1]^n$.

Comment: Thanks once! This observation now seems to solve the question I wrote in the comment above for you. Now, I believe that $\mathbb{R}^n$ \ {this Cantor set you are talking about} is connected.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry. Finite sets are always compact.

Comment: thanks for that answer, it helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Any compact subset of a subspace of lower dimension will have measure $0$ in the full space.

The unit sphere (not the unit ball) is a compact set with measure $0$. You can translate it so that it contains the origin.

Comment: thank you. That is fixing too.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever definition you use of compactness and of *measure zero*, the easiest example of $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with all the properties you like is $A = \{0\}$.

No matter if you use sequential compactness or compactness via open coverings, a singleton is trivially compact and of null Lebesgue measure.

Comment: thanks, that fixed my problem. But it seems to me that it's not trivial to get another example different from the trivial one.